# Drastic difference of the time cost for the same store procedure

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

**The process is actually like this:**

> First, about **2 million** records are pulled from a remote server,
>
> then a join is done locally,
>
> the final result is **thousands of records**.

The time cost varies from less one 1 min to 30 mins.

And after I experienced the 30 mins delay, it seems the following time costs are all only around 3 mins.

It is the **same** data, **same** SP.

What could cause this drastic difference?

### Update

I delet the SP, re-start the SQL server service, and re-creat the SP. The execution took only 50 seconds!

What's wrong?

Comment: How long does the s/p take to run if run on the server?  Thousands of records is small - shouldn't take more than seconds.

Comment: These thousands of records is the result of a join between several large tables on the remote server. I don't have permission to run the SP directly on the remote server.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you describe seems extreme - but (if you exclude the client), there are 3 logical places to look.

The first is the query execution on the database server. It's worth using the Query Analyzer tool to see if it's using any indices - by far the most common reason for variable performance of database queries is that the query is not using (the right) indices, and that therefore the impact of the query cache plays a big part. SQL Server will cache a lot of data, and the first run of your proc populates that cache; the second run is faster because it hits the cache. After a while, the cache goes stale, and running the proc slows down again.

The second possibility is that the database server is wobbly - it may just not be powerful enough to do all the work it's supposed to do. In that case, one moment you get lucky, have all the server resources to yourself; the next, someone else is running a query and yours slows down. That would make all queries slow, not just this one - so it doesn't sound likely.

Third possibility is networking weirdness - as Phil says, "thousands of records" is nothing too scary, but if they're big, and your network is saturated with pictures of kittens, it *might* have an impact. Again, that would manifest in general network slowness, and is unlikely to explain a delay of 30 minutes...

Answer (score 0):

Fourth, is anything going on at the same time?

Fifth, does your SP use dynamically generated SQL statements? This would cause the SP not to become pre-compiled. If possible seperate such statements into child SPs.